# display alert after button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that pops up an alert "Hello" after being clicked.
It works fine for the first click but after I close the alert and I clicked the button again, the alert doesn't shows. Please help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.hidden {
 display: none;
}
</style>
<title>Show Alert</title>
</head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container">

  <div class="row">
   <div class="alert alert-success hidden" id="success-alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Hello
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
   <button id="btn" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Open
    Alert</button>
  </div>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#btn").click(function() {
    $('#success-alert').removeClass('hidden');
   });

  });
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The alert box is getting removed by bootstrap. That is the problem.

Comment: you should add hidden class when alert box closed agian!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `hidden` class should come back but is not due to `data-dismiss`. Remove `data-dismiss` from your closing button and attach a click event to it which will give back the `hidden` class on click. Here's the working code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.hidden {
 display: none;
}
</style>
<title>Show Alert</title>
</head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container">

  <div class="row">
   <div class="alert alert-success hidden" id="success-alert">
    <button type="button" class="close">x</button>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Hello
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
   <button id="btn" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Open
    Alert</button>
  </div>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#btn").click(function() {
    $('#success-alert').removeClass('hidden');
   });
          $("button.close").click(function() {
    $('#success-alert').addClass('hidden');
   });

  });
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In Stack Overflow, it is better to point the problem too. not just pasting the code. Thanks :)

Comment: thank you for that. I included what was causing the problem too.

Comment: Thank you. I believe we should always try to specify the problem, and that is how we can help people, otherwise we are just improving the copy-paste skills :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because

Data-dismiss completely removes the element. Remove this attribute and bind the click event on close button, You can hide the alert using this event.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.hidden {
 display: none;
}
</style>
<title>Show Alert</title>
</head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container">

  <div class="row">
   <div class="alert alert-success hidden" id="success-alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" >x</button>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Hello
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
   <button id="btn" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Open
    Alert</button>
  </div>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#btn").click(function() {
    $('#success-alert').removeClass('hidden');
   });
          
            $(".close").click(function() {
    $("#success-alert").addClass('hidden');
   });
          

  });
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```